# Open projects legal advice

Tags: licensing

Hello I was wondering if your able to use the assets that blender cloud lets you download when you have a subscription to make a profit with them if you remodel them or leave as is and include them in your project.

To make a profit with them as is or remodeled do you need to have an active sub if you used one of there assets as a base model?

addressing (insert name here) to who have problems with my ? I came to this site from a link on blender clouds site so didint think there would be a problem with asking about them im sure since you 's all have such good grammar and there for probably think it means you have a big brain and there for like to show how big your brain is go arond on forums makeing sure ppl stick to the all so important rules as if its how you make your self feel valued but any way I'm sure you can tell how it is someone would assume me asking what I asked would be ok and as for it not being about blender I don't see how you can really say that the site teachers about useing blender the assets are for blender and the remodeling was suggested to be done in blender but since there all was seems to be tight ass on forums that wine about tiney things as well as grammar and spelling im sure thoughs tight ass wil focus on them things. To the one who answered my ?though I thank you for answering with out doing any of that wineing helping instead of hindering thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about *Blender Cloud* licensing and legal advice, not Blender application itself.

Comment: Licensing and legal questions are off topic please read: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/422/are-licensing-questions-off-topic/423#423

Comment: and this is a nother resion I don't like forums theres all wase a tight ass

Comment: @someone ... what did your last comment mean?  It is difficult to understand.

Comment: @someone everything has rules, not only licensing, even sites like this. Why you are so interested in blender cloud rules, but asking about those _here_ you can't understand this? and, insulting, too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, if it says **BY** you have to include the name of the artist it was by.
If it was **SA** (ShareAlike), your creation also has to be ShareAlike.

notes from  https://cloud.blender.org/blog/blender-cloud-v3

*Everything you find in Blender Cloud is either GNU GPL compliant software, or creative content that’s licensed as Creative Commons. We use three CC licenses here:*

*CC-BY: A permissive license that allows any re-use for as long you give a fair credit. It’s the default license. If you don’t see an explicit license mention on a web page, you can assume the works is CC-BY.*

*CC-0: This is similar to Public Domain. We want to license low level assets (textures, props) as CC0 as much as possible.*

*CC-BY-SA: The copyleft license. Any re-use is fine for as long you share it under the same (compatible) license. We use this for works we want to remain part of Free Culture.*

*Excluded from any of the above licenses are: Logos and trademarks (Blender logo, but also the film title designs), privacy and personality rights (people in pictures or videos are not CC themselves).*

Comment: ok thank you dose seem a bit deceptive by blender cloud thow if your not abil to use them how you like as that's how its read when you reed there big writing